# MySql - Contabilizar dados iguais na mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde a todos,

Tenho uma tabela chamada 'ms_msg_log'. Nessa tabela, tenho as colunas 'id_erro' e 'data_alt'.
Preciso que sejam exibidos os dados da seguinte forma:

id_erro = o valor normal do campo,

contabilização do id_erro mas somando apenas quando forem iguais,

data_alt

**Como os dados estão na Tabela**

Ex:

```
id_erro     data_alt

2           11-07-21

5           11-07-21

5           11-07-21

3           12-07-21

3           12-07-21

5           12-07-21

5           12-07-21

5           12-07-21

5           12-07-21

5           12-07-21

5           12-07-21

5           12-07-21
```

**Resultado esperado na consulta:**

Ex:

```
id_erro count data_alt

2           1 11-07-21

5           2 11-07-21

3           2 12-07-21

5           7 12-07-21
```

Caso não tenha conseguido explicar direito, posso tentar transmitir a idéia de forma mais clara.
Agradeço a todos pela atenção,

William

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

Answer (score -1):

Se consegui entender corretamente vc precisa de um group by

SELECT id_erro, COUNT(1), data_alt
FROM ms_msg_log
group BY id_erro, data_alt